# как ПЕРЕопределить место хранения образов и контейнеров DOCKER в линукс

Tags: linux, docker, администрирование, fat32

В общем проблема следующая: DOCKER установлен на рабочей станции fedora 29 которая полностью хранится на одном разделе порядка 50Г. В результате работы системный диск переполнился и необходимо перенести все тяжёлые файлы DOCKER: образы контейнеры и прочее что съело место, на существующий общий раздел Fat32. В этом собственно и вопрос. Как реализовать это изменение безошибочно и полноценно?

Comment: найти место где хранится можно например с помощью `du -s`, документации, strace'а или `/proc/*/fd`. на счёт перемещения на fat — скорей всего будут проблемы с правами и с размерами файлов... я бы этого делать поостерёгся... а прикрепить обратно можно с помощью симлинков или `mount -o bind`...

Comment: вопрос был как реализовать а не как узнать где находится. мне нужно в фат32 перекинуть директории которые будут заполняться DOCKERом тяжёлыми файлами. А где лежат я уже нашёл и сам, но предложенный вами способ заметно эстетичней, спасибо

Comment: вопрос один был задан и вы на него не ответили. я изначально не спрашивал как найти большие папки докера а как их определить то есть задать

Comment: вопрос как раз и заключается в том что решить проблемму и заставить докер полноценно пользоваться образами и контейнерами хранящимися в разделе фат32

Comment: я суть не менял, просто вы её не так поняли и я вопрос конкретизировал. Теперь ваш ответ меня устраивает и даже радует _)))

Comment: и всё-таки, вам на будущее: ваше первоначальное сообщене состояло из трёх несвязынных между собой вопросов (после редактирования осталось только два). моё же сообщение, содержащее три ответа, хотя и полезно вам лично, не несёт пользы другим людям, у которых могут возникнуть те же самые вопросы. потому я его удаляю. полезнее для других было бы отредактировать ваше сообщение, оставив один вопрос, и создать ещё два сообщения с остальными вопросами, а затем дать три отдельных ответа. но у меня на это нет ни времени ни желания.